# Magento 1.9.2.4 sub-category listing error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I managed to get sub-categories showing on the category page with images, but now since updating 1.9.2.1 up to 1.9.2.4 it no longer works. I cant imagine what may have changed and haven't altered anything.

I followed this tutorial:

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html#gref

Picture of it working in 1.9.2.1:

[image: working]

Picture of it not working in 1.9.2.4:

[image: not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are loading a special block type in a cms block.  You need to allow the block type catalog/navigation for it to display.  It's a very easy fix though;

You can do this in admin, from;

```
system > permissions > blocks
```

Or directly in the database in table permission_block.

Comment: Yes I found this out before, thanks for repyling. I have a similar conundrum where I am trying to use this extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all-category-product-carousel.html but it wont work, Ive tried adding pcarousel/pcarousel to the block permissions list. worked in 1.9.2.0.1